# embedding android mapview into HTML

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, webview, android-mapview

i am wondering if it is possible to embed an android view as part of html? Or to create a placeholder in the html code (like <div>) into which an android view can be loaded.
For example, my app's gui is made entirely using html and then loaded in a webview in the main android activity. What i'd like to do is to show a map inside the gui. I know i could just use the google maps javascript api, but since i already have the code written for dealing with the map using java, i am wondering if there's a simple way to just embed the native android google map view (the xml layout) into the html.

thanks,

Jaka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

However, if your WebView doesn't scroll, you can add your MapView on top of it, placing it right with the margin. And if it **does** scroll, you can move your MapView in its parent, according to the WebView current scroll (try subclassing WebView's [onScrollChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#onScrollChanged%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) method).